# Execute a command with parameter each filename in a folder

Tags: shell-script, csh

I would like to execute a command, let's call it abc and add as a parameter each filename in the current folder. How could I do this in C Shell (or other scripting language)?

Comment: Perhaps you can do just `abc *`? If not, explain more exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `csh` or `tcsh`, this would iterate over all the files and directories in the current directory.  I've used quotes around the `$i` variable substitution in case some of the names have spaces.

```
foreach i (*)
   abc "$i"
end
```

If you'd like to get only the files, not the directories, use the `-f` test.  Here I've used the C shell's short-form `if` statement.

```
foreach i (*)
   if (-f "$i") abc "$i"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Look up *xargs*. If your shell is anything like mine, the following should work nicely:

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 | xargs abc
```

If you are concerned about spaces in the file names, see Daniel Andersson's comment below.

Comment: This will give all files in subdirectories as well. It will also give all directories, though the question specifies "files" (but that might be unclear from the questioner). It will also break on every filename containing a space. `find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 abc` or `find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -exec abc {} +` would fix these points.

Comment: @DanielAndersson All valid comments... I updated my answer a bit. I can't remember the last time I saw a space in a file name on a *nix system though. :-)

Comment: @kmort I agree that filenames with spaces are rare on a Linux system but if you post an answer that doesn't consider the possibility (or at least point out that it will fail if there are spaces) someone is certain to jump on you here on the Superuser site.  It's just the way it is here.